# How to create a chart in iOS similar to the one in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, graph, charts

I have a collection of dates and sales in a MySQL Database and I would like to display the data similar to the way iTunes Connect does for app sales.

[image]

I have been looking at the iOS Charts framework but as far as I can see the framework only works with Swift. Is there any other Chart frameworks familiar to this?

Comment: So you want to write it in Objective-C?  This isn't very clear.

Comment: What about it are you trying to replicate? There's an entire screen of data here displayed in a few different ways.

Comment: Did you follow the Usage instructions from the [iOS Charts github page](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) step by step? It also explains how to use the framework with objective c.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not happy with Charts framework you can easily create your own graph view which will draw a graph like this one.

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90693/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-2) is a tutorial which should help you with that. The graph you showed is **really** not difficult to make on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) by Daniel Gindi

There is a Charts demo app inside the library, very useful.
You just need to implement the LineChartView class!
To give you and idea you can follow this awesome tutorial: appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial

With some style you can get something like this: [Chart-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwI1P.png)

```
popularityChartView.descriptionText = ""
popularityChartView.noDataText = Constants.messages.NO_POPULARITY_CHART_DATA
popularityChartView.noDataTextDescription = ""
popularityChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:236/255, green:236/255,blue:236/255,alpha:1)

popularityChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
popularityChartView.xAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = false
popularityChartView.xAxis.gridColor = UIColor(red:220/255, green:220/255,blue:220/255,alpha:1)
popularityChartView.xAxis.gridLineWidth = 0.5
popularityChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
popularityChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false

popularityChartView.leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines()
popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = false
popularityChartView.leftAxis.zeroLineWidth = 0
popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawTopYLabelEntryEnabled = false
popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
popularityChartView.leftAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = false

popularityChartView.rightAxis.removeAllLimitLines()
popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = false
popularityChartView.leftAxis.zeroLineWidth = 0
popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawTopYLabelEntryEnabled = false
popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
popularityChartView.rightAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = false
```

hope it helps!